# How to print directly without going to print dialog box in vb.net?

Tags: .net, printing

I'm trying to print a document using a default value without going to the print dialog box.

my code below prints in standard letter size (850, 1100) document even though I assign the value of 850, 1300.

```
Dim defaultsize As New Printing.PaperSize("Long Bond Paper", 850, 1300)
Dim pd = PrintDocument1
Dim ppd = PrintDialog1
ppd.Document = pd
pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = defaultsize
```

However, if I use the code below, it goes through the print dialog box and I would select the paper size from a combo box, it would print the document on an 850, 1300 paper.

```
If comboPaperSize.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
   PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = _
   PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(comboPaperSize.SelectedIndex)
End If
```

How could I print my document directly with the value of 850, 1300 without going through the print dialog box?.